# In the OED, one definition has three explanations separated by a semicolon and two use 'with' in italics: what does it mean?

Tags: dictionaries

In the OED, oen definition has three explanations separated by a semicolon and two use 'with' in italics: do I have to use 'with' to use that definition?

'Crowd'

> 7. a. To fill or occupy *with* a crowd or dense multitude; to fill to excess or encumbrance; to cram *with*.

All the examples use 'with', e.g.

> 1849   Macaulay Hist. Eng. I. 597   A port crowded with shipping.

I want to say that X crowds in Y, in sense 7a, that they fill it to excess.

So e.g.

- the trash crowds in the bin.

Or is that necessarily metaphorical?

Comment: What about: a bin  loaded/heaped with trash.

Comment: Your example context *the trash crowds in the bin* doesn't seem very idiomatic to me, but I'd say it's the full OED's definition 4: *intr. To push, or force one's way into a confined space, through a crowd, etc.; to press forward, up, etc. **Now only figurative**, as in quot. 1858, and coloured by 5.* I'd choose a different verb if I were you.

Comment: i might "crowd" trash into the bin, i guess, but the trash doesn't crowd in that sense? @FumbleFingers though i'm no physicist!

Comment: Different people will have different ideas about what usages are "acceptable / natural" in English. But on the grounds that no-one would be likely to say *The bin is crowded with trash*, I think you've just got the wrong verb in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers no you're right it's not "very idiomatic", just an intellectual exercise, of reading dictionaries, on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to match sense 7a you need the *with*<sup>1</sup>. That definition is for a particular use of the word which has the elements

> [container-type thing or space] [*crowded **with***] [individual things or people]

Those pieces can be arranged in slightly different ways (and the verb can be conjugated differently, of course), but you must have those pieces in that relation to one another: **the crowdedness describes the state of the *container-thing***.

Your sentence

> The trash crowds in the bin.

puts these elements in a different relationship with one another. Instead of the bin (container-thing) being the subject and describing it as *crowded with* the [pieces of] trash (individual things), in your sentence the trash is the subject, and you describe it as *crowding in* the bin. Here, **the crowdedness describes the state of the *trash*, not the state of the *bin***.

But don't despair! Your sentence is fine, it just matches a slightly different definition, the OED's sense 6b:

> To compress; to collect, bring, or pack closely together, as in a crowd.

And actually matches fairly closely the 1776 quotation for that sense, "*flowers crowded, in the bosom of the leaf-stalks.*"<sup>2</sup>

As an aside, the OED is primarily a descriptive dictionary, not a prescriptive dictionary. So I would tend to ask "*am* I using this word in this OED sense?" rather than "*can* I use this word in this OED sense?"

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You could also probably use *by*, but you haven't asked about that and I think *with* is usually going to be the better choice.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>The comma looks superfluous there to my eye; I think in modern writing we would not include it, making this a near-perfect analogue for your sentence.</sub>